# Python CMD module quit

Tags: python, cmd, module

I'm programming a simple text adventure game with Python 3 and the `cmd` module.

I need to somehow trigger the game over method but I didn't find a solution on document.

The `CMD` module got the `do_quit()` function, but that needs user input, and `quit()` or `exit()` kills the whole program, whereas I just need to get out of `cmdloop()`

Any idea how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance!

```
def moveDirection(direction):
global location

if direction in rooms[location]:
        if rooms[rooms[location][direction]].get(UNLOCKED, True) == True:
            print('You move to the %s.' % direction)
            location = rooms[location][direction]
            if location == 'Hallway' and bGuardAlive == True:
                print("Game over! Guard caught you!")

            printLocation(location)

        else:
            print("Door is locked")
else:
    print('You cannot move in that direction')


def main():
    printLocation(location)
    GameLoop().cmdloop()

class GameLoop(cmd.Cmd):
prompt = '\n> '

def do_quit(self, arg):
    """Quit the game."""
    return True
```

Comment: `break` is useful to exit loops.

Comment: we'd need to see some code

Comment: i added some code

Comment: Do you call self.moveDirection() from do_move_left(self, arg) function?

Answer (score 0):

Usually (if I understand correctly), you create you own class derived from `Exception`, you throw the exception at the place you want to exit, and you will have a `try` clause where you want to land.

Comment: This class is from CMD module https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/cmd.py.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error i get it working. I needed use `postcmd()`

Here is my code:

```
    def postcmd(self, stop, line):
    if bGuardAlive == False and location == 'Hallway':
        print("Game over! Guard caught you!")
        return True
    elif location == 'Tower Ruins':
        print("You won!")
        return True
    return stop
```

Hopefully this will help somebody